# Can I use Apache fallbackresource and rewrite at the same time?

Tags: apache, apache-config

I have an existing WordPress site using the default `.htaccess` mod_rewrite rules.

Now I want to add some separate PHP code to the site using a front-controller in it's own sub-dir. I use a `fallbackresource` directive in the Apache vhost config to do this, and end up with:

```
# New PHP front-controller based config
<directory "/srv/www/example.com/public/admin/products">
  AllowOverride None
  FallbackResource /admin/products/index.php
</directory>

# WordPress config
<directory "/srv/www/example.com/public">
  AllowOverride All
</directory>
```

This *almost* works! A request to `/admin/products` *does* correctly execute `/admin/products/index.php` -- it outputs a list of products. However, links to a specific product in the form `/admin/products/{prod-id}` end up getting passed to WordPress's `/index.php` script which gives me a WordPress generated 404.

I can workaround this by making the WordPress stuff also use a `fallbackresource` directive and not use `.htaccess` or rewrite rules, but I'd prefer to leave the WordPress bits working as they are.

```
# WordPress config
<directory "/srv/www/example.com/public">
  AllowOverride None
  FallbackResource /index.php
</directory>
```

Can anyone explain why the rewrite rules seem to take precedence over the `fallbackresource` directive?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own Q: Yes, I can use Apache `fallbackresource` *and* `rewrite` rules at the same time.

The reason it didn't work with the sample given was because the WordPress .htaccess rewrite rules were catching **all** requests including ones I wanted handled by my own front-controller, e.g. `GET /admin/products` was caught by the .htaccess rewrite rules and passed to /index.php

In the end I've decided to stick with a `fallbackresource` directive for WordPress and I'm using `AllowOverride None` to prevent .htaccess from being used at all.